# Fetch dynamic content based on wildcard subdomain

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull dynamic content from a database based on the wildcard subdomain.

Please see the code below.

```
<?php 
$data = $_GET['get'];

$data = addslashes(str_replace('-',' ',$data));
$town_result = $database->getData("select * from nationwide where town  = '$data' ");

if( is_object( $town_result ) )
{
    $area = $town_result->fetch_assoc();
}
else 
{
    $region_result = $database->getData("select * from nationwide where region  = '$data' ");

    if( !is_object( $region_result ) ) {
        header('Location: http://example.com');
    }
    $area = $region_result->fetch_assoc();
    $area['town'] = $area['region'];
}
?>
```

I have tried changing  `= '$data' ");` to `LIKE '%" . $data . "%'");` but this only pulls the first row in my database.

Comment: Have you tried to run the same query directly in the database to see how many records you are getting?

Comment: Constructing sql queries like that leaves your code _wide open_ to sql injection attacks. You do not want that. Please start reading and understand the benefits of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding".

Answer (score 2):

You can review how to use fetch_assoc to get associative records.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

You can print $area, then you can verify either array count is 1 or more than 1.
Or best way, you can print sql query and run directly in your db.